# Problems importing a CSV that has a filename as a string in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, csv, carrierwave

I'm trying to import a CSV file to my Rails app that's using CarrierWave to handle file uploads. I'm using the `CSV` gem and populating the Rails database via a seed data.

The issue I'm having is the import doesn't populate the image field of the database. The image column is a string that holds the filename eg. 'this-is-my-photo.jpg'.

I have a database table that has the following columns:

```
# ProductImage model, product_image table

id |     image    |     tile      | product_id | created_at | updated_at 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1 | image-1.jpg  | Big shoe      |     11     | 2012-08-01 | 2012-08-01
 2 | 1-photo.png  | Small hat     |     12     | 2012-08-01 | 2012-08-01
 3 | jeansb1.gif  | Ankle socks   |     13     | 2012-08-01 | 2012-08-01


# Import product_image table backup
CSV.foreach(Rails.root.join("db/seeds/product_image.csv"), headers: true) do |row|
  ProductImage.create! do |product_image|
    product_image.id = row[0]
    product_image.title = row[1]
    product_image.image = row[2]
    product_image.product_id = row[3]
  end
end
```

The results of `db:seed`

```
# ProductImage model, product_image table after population of seed data

id |     image    |     tile      | product_id | created_at | updated_at 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1 |              | Big shoe      |     11     | 2012-11-01 | 2012-11-01
 2 |              | Small hat     |     12     | 2012-11-01 | 2012-11-01
 3 |              | Ankle socks   |     13     | 2012-11-01 | 2012-11-01
```

Everything but the `image` column was populated.

I was wondering if anyone can give me tips on how to go about resolving this import/population issue. Has anyone experienced this problem before and is it because of the the filename type (eg. .jpg)?

Also, I have the same problem when restoring my user model that has an `avatar` column which is a string that holds the CarrierWave filename.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the `image=` method; that's a CarrierWave method *(overloading ActiveRecord's)*  which you're misusing when trying to set a string directly.

You can instead use [`write_attribute`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Write.html#method-i-write_attribute)

```
product_image.raw_write_attribute(:image, row[2])
```

This internally is what ActiveRecord uses inside it's `image=` method.

Comment: Hey Deefour, thank your taking the time to respond. I'm having a little issue with the write_attribute, I'm getting an error: private method `write_attribute' called for #<ProductImage:0x002fc49a2bg861>

Comment: I used the method raw_write_attribute to populate the image column. Thanks again Deefour for the insight. Great stuff.

Comment: Yeah, good for you; I'll update my answer to reflect that public alias.